# Is Possible select method start and method ending in jenkins?

Tags: nunit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I think this question is dumb but, my manager says that is possible,

Is possible i create a method and select this in somewhere to been method last test in the jenkins or nunit

I know is possible to do this with another projects, but method i think is possible.

I looking for over the internet, and try this, is possible select method to start put a **[setup]** up the method you can start.

but about the finish i find nothing about this.

am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Just like the `[Setup]` tag is run before your tests, if you specify a `[TearDown]` tag on a method, it will be run after all tests.

Note that this is a feature of Nunit and really has nothing to do with Jenkins.